# Can I reformat my Windows 8 partition without messing up my Windows 7 partition?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-8

I dual boot with both Windows 7 and 8. But I want to remove Windows 8 from the second partition that its on. I'm afraid this will mess up the boot routine it goes through and I wont be able to boot into Windows 7 anymore. Is this the case? If so, how can I safely remove Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow carefully the instructions form this guide and all will be ok: [How to Uninstall Windows 8, Windows 7 or Any Other Version of Windows](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-uninstall-windows-8-windows-7-or-any-other-version-windows).

Comment: Its good to answer here form references but please insert the helpful information in you answer that make it easy for others, just put the link for the further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can safely remove windows 8. Just follow these instructions:

**1.** Go to Windows 7 either format the Windows 8 drive or delete the respective files.

**2.** After that boot menu will disappear.

**3.** Then insert Windows 7 DVD.

**4.** Select repair and then select startup repair.

That's it

Comment: He should delete the Windows 8 boot entry first and set Windows 7 as the default boot OS. More details are in the solution I proposed.

Comment: that's no gonna work if windows 8 bootloader is installed