# Any easier way installing/uninstalling windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot

I want to try Windows 8 on my system but don't want to lose anything that is already installed so want some dual-boot system. I have a SSD installed having 2 partitions: `C:\` and `D:\`.

What I am looking here is to install Windows 8 somewhere on a new partition: `E:\`. and from boot screen I can switch what window I want to boot into.

After playing trying new Windows 8, I want to uninstall without disturbing the windows 7 that is already installed on my system.

Comment: Just delete the Windows 8 installation.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed instructions given at this link might help you:

[Can I reformat my Windows 8 partition without messing up my Windows 7 partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/467399/can-i-reformat-my-windows-8-partition-without-messing-up-my-windows-7-partition?rq=1)